# Song class not working properly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, media-player

In my silverlight `WP7` app, I am using XNA library to play sound. Following is the code.

```
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song s = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song.FromUri("song", new Uri("bmusic.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.Play(s);
```

It starts playing the sound and stops after a second, while the song is 10 secs long. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is event based, whereas XNA is more loop based. You need to enable XNA framework events, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff842408.aspx). As a quick test to see if that is the issue, in your page's constructor, you can add this:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30);
timer.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
timer.Start();
```